# Does the PA-44's squat switch disable the stall warning?

Tags: landing-gear, piper-pa-44

I've read the AFM and looked online about the gear system for the PA-44 Seminole and there is apparently a squat switch on the right main gear that disables the stall warning whilst on the ground. However during my pre-flight I have tested the stall warning with the battery master and avionics master on and it worked.

Is the stall warning squat switch not a feature on the newer PA-44s any more? The one I train in is about a year old now.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're talking about the stall warning? I believe you're talking about the horn that activates when in the landing configuration with no gear down(e.g throttle retarded, flaps down).

The 44 has 2 electric stall warning tabs that won't be actuated on the ground.

Comment: I think your answer is, "no, that aircraft never had a squat switch to disable the stall warning."  Which seems to be exactly the answer the OP needs. This post was flagged as "not an answer," which I think is incorrect, although a more direct phrasing of the response may help avoid such flags in the future.

Comment: I agree, think it's clear a no was implied in the answer, I'll try to be more direct in the future, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this but yes, the Seminole has a right main gear squat switch to disable the lift detectors on ground. The reason why you are able to test it, is because most operators or flight school disable it for this very reason. But yes, you’re right, it comes out of the factory with the lift detectors disabled by the right squat switch, not sure why.